# Google Calendar - how to delete entries using PHP?

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I'm working on syncing events from our project management DB into a google calendar using PHP.
Creating events in GCal works fine, but deleting them is proving to be a real pain, especially as there aren't any examples on how to do it.

Has anyone done this before in PHP (not on Zend Framework)?

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont want to use zend?

Give a look at [php nusoap class](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/920.html), but i strongly raccomand Zend.

It's the simplyest way to do that: [here](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/apis/calendar/data/1.0/developers_guide_php.html) you'll find the full php google calendar api, and [here how to delete events.](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/apis/calendar/data/1.0/developers_guide_php.html#DeletingEvents)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Daniel, I'll check that out.

On Zend: I'd love to use it, but our company doesn't want to take the plunge just yet. I guess I could use this to persuade them...

Cheers

Comment: I understand.. well, google around for 'google calendar php class', and you should find many classes.. i didnt try them, so i cant suggest any of them